Daily Budget and Date on Google Ad Words API
I am trying to integrate Google Ad Words and Salesforce and I am trying to fetch the campaign_budget.amount_micros and 'daily budget date'. I am getting the budget amount from campaign_budget.amount_micros. However, I am not sure the exact field which stores the date.
I tried checking the query validator but still couldn't figure out the exact field or even if the date is actually stored or not. https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v16/campaign_query_builder
